# Angular 5 BehaviorSubject with multiple boolean values

Tags: angular

I made a service which can watch a component for data change and update in another componenet

**service.ts**

```
isValue: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
cast = this.isValue.asObservable();
constructor() { }
chageValue() {
  this.isValue.next(!this.isValue.value);
}
}
```

**child1.ts**

```
isValue: boolean;
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.castValue.subscribe(data => this.isValue = data);
}
changeValue() {
  this.sharedService.chanageValue();
  console.log('value: ' + this.isvalue);
}
```

**Child2.ts**

```
isValue: boolean;
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.castValue.subscribe(data => this.isValue = data);
  console.log('value' + this.isValue);
  changeValue() {
    this.sharedService.chanageValue();
    console.log('value: ' + this.isvalue);
  }
```

and now I want to another Boolean variable.so, I want to know is there a way to add it other than just adding the same blocks with different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define an anonymous type:

```
x: BehaviorSubject<{isValue: boolean, isValue2: boolean}>
   = new BehaviorSubject({isValue: false, isValue2: true});
```